# Bootstrap navbar auto collapse issue with Wordpress menu

Tags: wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, navbar

Care: the example url's are from a development site for a non profit organization which helps children with a harelip in Venezuela. So there will be some pictures there that people prefer not to see.

I'm building the [site](http://develop.cpp.nl/tessunlimited/#home) with Twitter Bootstrap and have the navbar working with the wp_nav_menu without any problems.

Due #anchors in the nav on the homepage, it doesn't reload after click. Therefor the nav won't collapse back to its closed state. (so see the collapse button, resize your screen).

What I need is this: http://jsfiddle.net/hajpoj/By6ym/4/

Iv'e tried the stuff in the fiddle example and that worked seamless so it must be due additional classes / id's in the jQuery or something.

My jQuery ain't good enough to find or create a clean sollution.
Up until

The PHP:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse">
<div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
        <a data-target=".navbar-responsive-collapse" data-toggle="collapse" class="btn btn-navbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </a>
        <p class="brand hidden-desktop">Menu</p>
        <div class="nav-collapse collapse navbar-responsive-collapse ss-icon">
        <?php $sitenavigatie = array(
            'theme_location'  => 'header-menu-left-page',
            'menu_class'      => 'menu',
            'echo'            => true,
            'fallback_cb'     => 'wp_page_menu',
            'items_wrap'      => '<ul id="%1$s" class="nav %2$s">%3$s</ul>',
            'depth'           => 0,
            'walker'          => new TessWalkerMenu());
            wp_nav_menu( $sitenavigatie ); ?>
        </div> <!-- end .nav-collapse .collapse .navbar-responsive-collapse -->
    </div> <!-- end .container-fluid -->
</div> <!-- end .navbar-inner -->
```

The jQuery in the Fiddle:

```
$('.nav-collapse').click('li', function() {
  $('.nav-collapse').collapse('hide');
});
```

Hope somebody can help.

Answer (score 0):

update fiddle, pl see in link

jsfiddle.net/By6ym/23/

Answer (score 0):

try add document ready or on window load.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('.nav-collapse').click('li', function() {
    $('.nav-collapse').collapse('hide');
  });
```

});